# Centered signup form box with sticky footer, resizing problems

Tags: css, sass

Here's the example of what I have so far:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQZpNw

My objective is to center that box in the middle to the center of the page, and have the rest of the elements respond appropriately. I've ended up using `margin-top: 10%;` as a way to center the box, but the problem with this approach is that on smaller browser heights users will have to scroll. It's also not perfectly centered.

Ideally, what I'm looking for, is to:

- Center the box (vertically and horizontally)
- On small browser heights the center box should sit just underneath the navbar with a small margin, to eliminate the scrolling on small browsers.
- Sticky the footer with a gap between the footer and the box when the browser height is really small.
- When the center box expands its contents or the navbar expands its contents everything else should move appropriately and not overlap.

I made some javascript buttons to expand the navbar and centerbox so it's easier to experiment with. My actual app is obviously different, this is a stripped down version of what I have.

I tried a bunch of different things to get this to work with no luck, when I used calc() to set it to the center on small browser heights the footer or navbar would overlap the box. I'm out of ideas now, and CSS is not my strong suit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a full page wrapper with a header, the footer, and the div you want centered. Using `display:flex;` with the `flex-direction` set to `column` and `justify-content: space-between;` you can basically center the div. It will be off a little bit if your header and footer are different sizes but you won't need a ton of media queries or code that is hard to maintain. Set the `min-height` of the wrapper to `100vh` and your footer will be sticky, unless the window is too short to fit all of the pieces.

```js
$('#nav-button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#nav-content').toggleClass('expand');
});
```

```css
header {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

header a {
  color: white;
}

#nav-content {
  height: 0;
  transition: height .3s;
}

#nav-content.expand {
  height: 300px;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

#centered-box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href='#' id="nav-button">Expand</a>
      <div id="nav-content"></div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div id="centered-box"></div>

  <footer>This is the footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm having trouble getting it to work with what I have, here's what it looks like in my example (unless I'm doing something wrong?): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OaBNPb

Getting the same behavior in my actual app as well. Any idea?

Comment: Another thing is that because this uses a wrapping div around all of those elements it's going to be problematic to use across the rest of the site for pages that don't follow this sort of center-aligned convention (which will probably be most other pages). Makes templating things hard.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/pQQgEg - If you remove the absolute positioning from the footer I think it works great. You can make it so the wrapper style is only applied on a particular page by including the page template class that is being added to the body tag in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using media queries at all in your CSS? Media queries allow you to style elements a certain way if the browser window size falls within the query.

Comment: Yeah Bulma will remove this problem on mobile-size using media queries, it's only an issue for desktop browser windows with odd dimensions (i.e. high width small height).

Comment: You can use media queries for more than just mobile. If you want the elements to appear differently on a screen using your example:  

    `@media (min-height: 800px) and (min-width: 1200px) {
        /* CSS stuff */
    }`

and you can set the query to whatever you'd like, that was just an on the fly height and width.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I said mobile-size not mobile ;). it's not really feasible to use media queries for this though, I'd have to make too many of them to cover all of the bases. Appreciate the thought though.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question before. Try this update codepen https://codepen.io/joeybreithaupt/pen/VVVwvm and let me know if thats what you’re looking for. If it is I can explain it when I get home if you need me to, I’m replying from my phone at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, but this has the same the problem as my original, when you resize that window (drag the top border down past the box) you'll see that the middle box and its contents hides under the footer and the header, instead of stopping at them and making a scrollbar.

Comment: So I built a [new pen](https://codepen.io/joeybreithaupt/pen/KrraGj) to start from scratch and hopefully achieve the look you're going for. I just threw it together style wise but functionality should be spot on! Let me know!